# $f( \alpha x + \beta y) =\alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

My friend had the first Math 101 Class in University, and he really finds its hard and he says the lecturer didn't teach this well. Can anyone give me a proof for this property in linear algebra-

$f( \alpha x + \beta  y) =\alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$

And also when it might come into use.

Comment: What are $f$, $x$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Comment: Exactly this is what the lecturer put on the black board. Even i was confused as to how to explain to him , thats why i put up this question if anyone is aware of this property.

Comment: What you wrote is not enough. You must say what are $f$, $x$,... for your formula to make sense. In *linear algebra*, if $\mathbb{K}$ is a field (say $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) and $E,F$ are two $\mathbb{K}$-linear spaces, a mapping $f \, : \, E \, \rightarrow \, F$ is said to be **linear** if and only if : 

$$ \forall (x,y) \in E^{2}, \, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{K}, \, f(\alpha x + y) = \alpha f(x) + f(y) $$

This is the "natural" context in which such a formula appears.

Comment: My guess is that x and y are variables, alpha and beta are just constants, and f is the symbol for function

Comment: In linear algebra, $x,y$ are *vectors*, $\alpha,\beta$ are *scalars* and $f$ is a *linear map* (there is some specific vocabulary here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a definition, not something to be proved. In this case, it's a definition of a linear transformation. For instance, given vectors $x,y$ and a matrix $A$,
$$A(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha A x + \beta A y$$
Thus, multiplication by a matrix is a linear transformation. If $x,y$ are scalars, then only functions of the form $f(x) = mx$ satisfy this requirement, and as these are equations of straight lines, this class of transformations is called linear transformations.

Other examples include the definite and indefinite integral, which are also linear transformations.

Comment: @Leonhard - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really clearly stated your question. Answering my best guess at what you're trying to ask, the identity you wrote is the *definition* of the phrase "$f$ is a linear transformation" (where $x,y$ range over all vectors and $\alpha,\beta$ range over all scalars), so there's nothing to prove.

My next best guess is that you have a slightly different definition of "$f$ is a linear transformation" which involves different identities... and the identity you wrote is a simple consequence of those identities. (and vice versa)

Comment: even I was confused as to what my friend told, because he didnt understand as well, he just told me the lecturer wrote it down. I think alpha and beta are just numbers, and x and y are unknowns, and f is the function sign. Actually he hasnt learnt about vectors still, it was the first class in university.

Comment: The number line happens to be a one-dimensional vector space, so we can think of numbers as vectors if we like. The synonym "linear function" would be more commonly used in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your lecturer has written on the board a property which is only satisfied by certain functions. This property does not hold for all functions $f$, so those functions for which it does hold are regarded as "interesting" and "useful". That's why your lecturer put this property on the board in the first place! Nothing is done in mathematics without good cause.

Why would your lecturer do this? Well just think how useful this property is. If we are dealing with a function which has this property then we can use the property to perform algebraic manipulations in exactly the way the property allows.

And using the property will no doubt enable us to reach some interesting results from some initial assumptions.